# Sampling from posterior

Tags: self-study, sampling, posterior

Assume that the likelihood is available in closed form $p(Y|X)$. And also the prior is available in close form $p(X)$ and it is easy to sample from.

Then the posterior
$p(X|Y) = c p(Y|X)p(X)$

Usually the difficulty is in the calculation of the normalizing constant $c$.

Assume we calculated $c$.

How can we sample from the posterior? 
Do we use rejection sampling?  Sampling from prior with acceptance probability $c$ $p(Y|X)$? But this value is not actually a probability. It can be greater than 1!

Comment: is this is HW please add the `self-study` tag

Comment: Hi Antoine. Im not sure i understand what you wrote.. this is not a hw. Do i add the self study tag or not?

Comment: Do you have a specific prior and likelihood that you are interested in, or is this a general question?

Comment: This is a general question. Almost always when reading about Bayesian inference, the main challenge is the computation of the normalizing factor. Assume we managed to compute it in one way or another. Then the posterior as a pdf is given by a constant depending on x multiplied by the prior. My question is how to sample from the posterior in this form. This is interesting for example if one wants to use gibbs sampler and each conditional density ends up in the above form.

Comment: In many cases if the posterior has analytical form, it is a widely acknowledged distribution like normal or beta. In this case an engineer can use his favorite package to sample from this common distribution. If we have a completely new distribution, we can try something like inverse transform sampling.

Comment: Here the distribution is given as a product $c p(Y|X)p(X)$ which in general not reduced to a normal/beta or a similar standard distribution.

Comment: any progress on this?